# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, undefined

```
function lockCells(spreadsheet, cell, rangeToLock) {
  // Get the value of the specified cell
  var cellValue = spreadsheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
  // If the cell value is true, lock the specified range of cells
  if (cellValue === true) {
    spreadsheet.getRange(rangeToLock).setLocked(true);
  // Call the lockCells function to lock cells A1:A5 if cell B1 is set to TRUE
lockCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),"B1","A1:A5");
  }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')
> lockCells   @ LockCells.gs:3

How to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

when calling `lockCells` you are not sending the value for `spreadsheet` which makes it undefined. Hence you are facing the following error

Make the following changes in the code:

```
var cellValue;
if(spreadsheet != undefined)
     cellValue = spreadsheet.getRange(cell).getValue();

if(spreadsheet != undefined)
    spreadsheet.getRange(rangeToLock).setLocked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with the code you quote is that it attempts to use a method called `Range.setLocked()` which does not exist.

To lock cells, use the [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class.